# jQuery - How to add input while retaining values of previous inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I would like to add new inputs using jQuery, however, after clicking the add input which uses jQuery to add another of such element below, it removes the inputs before.

```js
var num = 2;
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click", addInput);

function addInput() {
  var newInput = `
<div>
<input type="date" id="start" name="avail[startdate${num}] value="" min="" max="" />
<input type="range" name = "avail[startdate${num}] value="" min="0" max="23" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" >
<output>12</output><span>:00 (GMT+8) </span>
</div>
`
  // '<input type="text" name="input'+num+'"/><br> <br>';
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += newInput;
  num++;
}
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]').forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('mousedown', () => window.getSelection().removeAllRanges());
});
```

```html
<p>Availability</p>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="">
    <input type="date" id="start" name="avail[startdate1]" value="" min="" max="">
    <input type="range" value="" name="avail[startdate1]" min="0" max="23" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
    <output>12</output><span>:00 (GMT+8) </span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add input" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Catch your elements (in example `parent`). Using `insertAdjacentHTML` you can append new element on catching element without loosing previous state of range.

Example:

```js
var num = 2;
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click", addInput);

function addInput() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('demo');
  var newInput = `
<div>
<input type="date" id="start" name="avail[startdate${num}] value="" min="" max="" />
<input type="range" name = "avail[startdate${num}] value="" min="0" max="23" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" >
<output>12</output><span>:00 (GMT+8) </span>
</div>
`
  // '<input type="text" name="input'+num+'"/><br> <br>';
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newInput);
  num++;
}
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]').forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('mousedown', () => window.getSelection().removeAllRanges());
});
```

```html
<p>Availability</p>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="">
    <input type="date" id="start" name="avail[startdate1]" value="" min="" max="">
    <input type="range" value="" name="avail[startdate1]" min="0" max="23" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
    <output>12</output><span>:00 (GMT+8) </span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add input" />
```

Answer (score -1):

By using  `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML` you are updating the current HTML inside the **demo** div. you may use another id or instead of `innerHTML` you may use jQuery `append`.